# R - Using Subset with get() in a Loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

If I have a list of dataframes like here - with reproducible example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    'Country' = sample(c("United States", "Canada"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    'Region' = sample(c("Unknown"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
df2 <- data.frame(
    'Country' = sample(c("United States", "Canada"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    'Region' = sample(c("Unknown"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
df3 <- data.frame(
    'Country' = sample(c("United States", "Canada"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    'Region' = sample(c("Unknown"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

dflist <- c('df1', 'df2', 'df3')
```

When I loop through the DFs like below, I get an error for the subset line.

```
for (i in unique(dflist)) {
  print(paste(i, nrow(get(i)), sep = ','))
  subset(get(i), site_country_code == 'United States')$Region <<- 'NA'
}
```

I get this:

```
[1] "df1,10"

Error in subset(get(i), site_country_code == "United States")$Region <<- "North America" : 
  object 'i' not found
```

The print line seems to work - returns the name of the df and the row count. However the subset fails with this 'i' not found error. Doesn't subset understand get(i)? is there a way around this?

Comment: You may try `lst1 <- lapply(mget(dflist),function(x) {x$Region[x$Country=='United States'] <- NA; x})` and to change it in the original dataset. `list2env(lst1, envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: @akrun I get "<environment: R_GlobalEnv>" and it doesn't seem to have changed it?

Comment: Check your `df1`, `df2`

Comment: @Akrun - sorry to clarify, it does work with 'NA' - but changes it to NA and I can't change that value to anything else, like a string- still makes them <NA>

Comment: I need 'NA' as in 'North America' not NA as in Missing values which seems to be produced with your code - this happens even if I change it to: 
lst1 <- lapply(mget(dflist),function(x) {x$Region[x$Country=='United States'] <- 'NA'; x}) # still gives <NA> not 'NA'

Comment: Your columns are factors.  You may need to change it to character.  class. Please check my updated post.

Comment: You could still work with factors if you can add `NA` as one of the levels of `Region` before assigning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  lst1 <- lapply(mget(dflist), function(x) {
           x$Region <- as.character(x$Region)
           x$Region[x$Country == "United States"] <- "NA"
           x
         })
```

In the above code, `mget` returns the values of the vector `dflist` in a `list`.  Used `lapply` to process the list.  Converted the `factor` column `Region` to `character` class before assigning `Region` code to `NA` for the `United States` Country.  Then use `list2env` to reflect the changes in the original dataset.

```
  list2env(lst1, envir=.GlobalEnv)
  #<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

  head(df1,4)
  #      Country  Region
 #1        Canada Unknown
 #2        Canada Unknown
 #3        Canada Unknown
 #4 United States      NA
```

If you don't want to change the column to `character`, you could first create a `NA` level for the `Region` before doing the assignment.

```
 lst1 <- lapply(mget(dflist), function(x) {
      levels(x$Region) <- c(levels(x$Region), "NA")
      x$Region[x$Country == "United States"] <- "NA"
      x
    })
```

and then use `list2env`